# asp.net identity "the function evaluation require all thread to run"

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-identity

I have trying to customize IdentityUser. I have create BaseController use get LoginUser in every page instead implement getting method in each page.

Here is my LoginUser in BaseController

```
public AtfmUser LoginUser
    {
        get
        {
            if(_loginUser == null)
            {
                if(User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
                {
                    _loginUser = AtfmUserManager.FindByName(User.Identity.Name);
                }
            }

            return _loginUser;
        }
    }
```

However when I ran project I got error message ""the function evaluation require all thread to run".

I don't have any async method.

Please help, thank you ^^

Edit: more information in my BaseController

```
    public AccountUserManager AtfmUserManager { get; private set; }

    public RoleManager<AtfmRole> AtfmRoleManager { get; private set; }

    private AtfmUser _loginUser;

    public BaseController()
        : base()
    {
        AccountDbContext context = new AccountDbContext();
        AccountStore<AtfmUser> userStore = new AccountStore<AtfmUser>(context);
        AtfmUserManager = new AccountUserManager(userStore);
        RoleStore<AtfmRole> roleStore = new RoleStore<AtfmRole>(context);
        AtfmRoleManager = new RoleManager<AtfmRole>(roleStore);
        _loginUser = null;
    }
```

Comment: Are you getting this message when running the code normally? Usually this is something you would see when inspecting a value when debugging: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/eliofek/archive/2012/12/12/why-do-we-get-the-function-evaluation-requires-all-threads-to-run.aspx

Comment: Yes. I see this error message while I debug an error ( LoginUser return null ).